# Ansible not becoming root when run from Bitbucket Pipeline

Tags: ansible, bitbucket-pipelines, packer, amazon-linux-2

I am running Packer + Ansible provisioner from the Bitbucket pipeline. but ansible not becoming root even `become: true` is given. Packer is used to create an Amazon Linux AMI and Ansible provisioner is used to run some server hardening scripts and configurations.

output from simple id command:
When run from Pipeline

```
TASK [aws-basic : debug] *****************************************
 ok: [default] => {
 "command_output.stdout_lines": [
     "uid=1000(ec2-user) gid=1000(ec2-user) groups=1000(ec2-user),4(adm),10(wheel),190(systemd-journal)"
  ]
}
```

When running from Locally

```
    TASK [aws-basic : debug] *****************************************
 ok: [default] => {
 "command_output.stdout_lines": [
     "uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)"
  ]
}
```

Following is my Ansible Playbook with two roles

```
- name: AWS EC2 AMLinux Configuration playbook
  hosts: default
  remote_user: ec2-user
  connection: ssh
  become: true


  vars:
    _date: "{{ansible_date_time.iso8601}}"
    reop_path: /usr/tmp/

  roles:
   - role: role-1
   - role: role-2
```

Packer ansible provisioner config

```
  provisioner "ansible" {
    playbook_file = "../ansible/aws-ec2-base.yml"

    extra_arguments = ["--extra-vars", "api_key=${var.api_key}"]
    galaxy_file     = "../ansible/requirements.yml"
    ansible_ssh_extra_args = ["-oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -oPubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa"]
  }
```

Even putting become_user: root in the ansible-playbook is not working.

Any reason this only happens in the bitbucket pipeline? I am using an ubuntu docker image with Ansible and Packer installed.

Comment: Please show us an example playbook that is not working. Mind that, in order to switch to a different user, you have to have a couple of `become` and `become_user` (where `become_user` should default to `root`, but can be otherwise based configuration you can set at multiple levels like in your inventory, your playbook, ...)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε playbook runs a simple bash script and datadog ansible role from ansible galaxy which both require sudo. this works without errors locally but lacks root permissions when running from the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

My gut is there would be some config in each system that triggers a different behaviour. I'd try

```
ansible-config dump --only-changed
```

in both your local workstation and the CI system and try to peek any difference that might be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused because of the use of an older version of the packer plugin.
can also resolve the issue by using a bitbucket runner.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that the container image I built (containing packer/ansible/gcloud) that I used in the bitbucket pipeline for building a GCP image via packer/ansible defaulted to `root` user.
When executing an ansible-playbook the `become:true` seemed to be ignored as `id` was not showing `root` in the target VM.

Updating this user to any other user in the Dockerfile of the build image resolved the issue.

i.e. adding:

```
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash bitbucket
USER bitbucket
```